# Detecting when SerialPort is ready for next command

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a piece of hardware that I'm connecting to using the .NET SerialPort class over RS232.
According to its documentation it doesn't support any type of flow control.

I can write queries and commands to the device, for the queries it'll respond immediately to a read, and if echo is on for the device and I have to do a read after writing a command then the command writes work fine too.  The commands and responses are a maximum of 7 characters.

However if echo is off and I write 2 commands in quick succession the second one isn't carried out, unless I put in a Thread.Sleep(15) between the writes, presumably replicating the time it takes to do the ReadLine when echo is on.

I can't necessarily guarantee that echo will be on, and explicitly turning it on isn't really an option either, so I basically need to handle the behaviour as I find it.

The SerialPort is set up as follows:

```
SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort
{
    PortName = "COM1",
    BaudRate = 9600,
    Parity = Parity.None,
    DataBits = 8,
    ReadTimeout = 5000,
    WriteTimeout = 5000,
    NewLine = "\x0D"
};
```

And I'm using WriteLine and ReadLine to communicate with it.

Sleeping the thread feels like a hack, and I haven't found an alternative with all my googling.
So, have I missed something, is there some way I can check when the next command write to a serialport can be carried out or is Thread.Sleep pretty much my lot?

Comment: Does waiting until all of your command payload's bytes have been sent on the wire work?

Comment: Also there probably is no difference between Thread.Sleep(15) and Thread.Sleep(1) and perhaps Thread.Sleep(0) is good enough to force a context switch (I think ?) EDIT reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @kenny: How can I tell when all the bytes have been sent? Is it the BytesToWrite property? If so, that is 0 immediately after I send it. The command is only 7 bytes, so it's not going to take long to send but it appears to take a while for the hardware to react. 

I've tried varying the Thread.Sleep duration, and 10 actually seems to be the sticking point, less than 10  = problem, greater than 10 = ok.

Comment: I just gave Thread.Sleep(0) a go but it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @nanhyudrin yeah, from memeory I was thinking BytesToWrite. It must be a problem with the design of your device. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately due to the lack of support in my system for flow control Thread.Sleep seems to be the solution.
I've set up my code so that it checks to see if echo is on and then if it is it just uses the ReadLine, and if it's off then it uses a Thread.Sleep(15).
It feels nasty, but it works reliably, so I'm just having to go with that.

Answer (score 0):

http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/SerialPort-_2800_RS_2D00_232-Serial-COM-Port_2900_-in-C_2300_-.NET.aspx

Set handshake property to RTSCTS and handle the PinChanged event when CTS becomes true?

> Lines marked ‘Output’ in the table can be set by the serial port to a high or low state (True or > > False) and the ‘Input’ lines can be read as high or low.  You can use the PinChanged event to be > > notified when one of the input pins changes.  The Handshake property can be set to use RTS/CTS > > > (uses hardware control lines) or XON/XOFF (uses software) or both.
>
> Control Line Name DB9 Pin SerialPort Property I/O
> DTR Data Terminal Ready 4 DtrEnable Output
> RTS Request to Send 7 RtsEnable Output
> CTS Clear to Send 8 CtsHolding Input
> DSR Data Set Ready 6 DsrHolding Input
> CD (or DCD) Data Carrier Detect 1 CDHolding Input

Comment: That assumes the device supports that and the cable has them connected as well. BTW: this is a type of flow control and the OP states the device doesn't support flow control.

Comment: As I understand it the value of CTS will only change when the input buffer is full or after it's been full and cleared? 
But the input buffer is like 4096 bytes minimum in size according to the SerialPort documentation, so surely there's pretty much no chance that my commands will ever cause it to change the CTS status?

Comment: If the device doesn't support any type of flow control then it won't ever raise CTS to tell you it's OK to send. You'll raise RTS when the buffer is almost full (if the device supported flow control). Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having a similar problem. Using a low baud rate I was attempting to write commands to the port too fast (apparently the "write" command returns before the write is finished).

I solved this by modifying the "Serial Port Ready?" function I call before each command. I added a while loop to sleep for 5ms while the "BytesToWrite" property was greater than zero. Worked fine after that.